# Unmatching a Palindrome in a string in regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to unmatch the palindromes observed in a set of words.I'm able to write the syntax to match palindromes.However,I am finding it difficult to write a syntax that unmatches the palindromes and print the rest.

For Example,The syntax should match these set of words.

```
acritan
aesthophysiology
amphimictical
baruria
```

and leave the words such has

```
anallagmatic
bassarisk
chorioallantois
coccomyces
commotive
engrammatic
glossoscopia
```

If you observe the above words have palindromes in the middle like

```
anallagmatic has "alla" in the middle
engrammatic  has  "amma" in the middle
```

So here is my syntax for capturing the palindromes.

```
(\w)(\w)\2\1
```

I need a syntax that captures the opposite  of what my above syntax is capturing

Comment: What's the language?

Comment: What about palidromes like `racecar`?

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?!.*?(\w)(\w)\2\1).+$
```

You can simply use a `negative lookahead` to make sure there is no palindrome.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rL8wP1/6

Answer (score 0):

Use alternation operator

```
\S*(\w)(\w)\2\1\S*|(\S+)
```

get the string you want from group index 3.

If you're on PHP, you may use `(*SKIP)(*F)`

```
\S*(\w)(\w)\2\1\S*(*SKIP)(*F)|\S+
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eP4nF7/2)